# parts inside augroup can't be highlighted in $MYVIMRC

Tags: vim, vi

```
augroup jsgroup
autocmd!
autocmd FileType javascript iabbrev <buffer> iff if ()<left>
problem ---> autocmd FileType javascript iabbrev <buffer> ffn function() {<CR><BS><SPACE><CR>}<ESC>?{<CR>j$a
autocmd FileType javascript iabbrev <buffer> rtn return;<left>
autocmd FileType javascript iabbrev <buffer> log/ console.log()<left>
augroup END
```

can someone tell me what is wrong with this $MYVIMRC code? 
The problem is FileType and buffer Doesn't highlight at the 4th,5th and 6th line.

It might be because of the last brace '{' of the 4th line, which is to be run on normal mode of vim. If this is the problem, how do i escape the brace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets sidestep this issue completely. Use the `after` directory to use these settings.

Put the following line into `~/.vim/after/ftplugins/javascript.vim`:

```
iabbrev <buffer> iff if ()<left>
iabbrev <buffer> ffn function() {<CR><BS><SPACE><CR>}<ESC>?{<CR>j$a
iabbrev <buffer> rtn return;<left>
iabbrev <buffer> log/ console.log()<left>
```

This makes it easier to maintain filetype specific settings.

For more help see:

```
:h after-directory
:h ftplugin
```